# Golang encrypt message Fix go-crypt()

Tags: go, crypt, password-checker

```
package main

import(

crypt "github.com/amoghe/go-crypt"
)
```

Running the code above gives err:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/tools/gos/SUnix# go run crack.go

 github.com/amoghe/go-crypt
/root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/amoghe/go-crypt@v0.0.0-20191109212615-b2ff80594b7f/crypt_r.go: In function ‘gnu_ext_crypt’:
/root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/amoghe/go-crypt@v0.0.0-20191109212615-b2ff80594b7f/crypt_r.go:35:3: warning: 'strncpy' specified bound depends on the length of the source argument...
```

[this is bad image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qw69.png) how can I fix it

Answer (score 0):

This warning is printed by the C compiler (the file `crypt_r.go` includes inline code in the C language) to warn the author/users that the code includes a potential issue. In this case the warning can be safely ignored but if you want it fixed it's probably best to raise a PR/issue on the [appropriate repository](https://github.com/amoghe/go-crypt/issues).

`warning 'strncpy' specified bound depends on the length of the source argument` means that it's bad practice to base the length of a string copy on the length of the source; if you do this and the source is longer than the destination buffer then you have a buffer overflow which is bad!. However in this case the destination buffer is created on the line above the `strncpy` so it's unlikely to be an issue (unless the allocation fails for some reason).

This kind of thing can cause real issues in applications written in C (and many other languages); fortunately go protects you (it will panic rather than overwrite the buffer) unless you use the unsafe package (or include C code!).

Comment: ok ı understand bu ı dont know how can ı edit this github file and how can ı import it , like this ? import ("~/Downloads/go-crypt")

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure what you mean?  From your screenshot it looked like this was compiling/running OK (it was displaying a warning but that should not stop it functioning). If you really want to fix this warning yourself your best bet would be to setup a github account and fork the repository (then import from your fork).